# pandas: iterate with conditionals within group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks similar to this (note this is an example, my actual dataframe has thousands of rows with hundreds of groups)

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
              'year':[2018, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020], 
              'c':[1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3]})

   a  year  c
0  A  2018  1
1  A  2019  2
2  A  2020  4
3  B  2018  2
4  B  2020  4
5  C  2018  4
6  C  2019  4
7  C  2020  3
```

I need to check the following conditions for each group in column 'a':

1. is one row for each year (ie. 2018, 2019, 2020) existent
2. does the value in column 'c' increase from one year to the next, ie. is the value higher for 2020 than 2019 than 2018

if both conditions are True I like to set a "TRUE" value in column 'd' for that group

```
   a  year  c   d
0  A  2018  1  TRUE
1  A  2019  2  TRUE
2  A  2020  4  TRUE
3  B  2018  2  FALSE
4  B  2020  4  FALSE
5  C  2018  4  FALSE
6  C  2019  4  FALSE
7  C  2020  3  FALSE
```

in my example only group A fulfills both conditions. group B has no data for 2019 and group C the values do not increase from one year to the next.

i have tried groupby but just dont get anywhere. I think this calls for iterows but dont know how to start.

Comment: How is the _one row per year_ condition determined? How we do know the first and last year to check for?

Comment: Also, is it one **and only one** row for each year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do condition with `apply` + `reindex`

```
df['cond']=df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x : pd.Series([2018,2019,2020]).isin(x['year']).all() & x['c'].diff().fillna(1).gt(0).all()).reindex(df.a).values
df
   a  year  c   cond
0  A  2018  1   True
1  A  2019  2   True
2  A  2020  4   True
3  B  2018  2  False
4  B  2020  4  False
5  C  2018  4  False
6  C  2019  4  False
7  C  2020  3  False
```

Comment: thanks. i added a sort values by year 

df['cond']=df.sort_values('year').groupby('a').apply(lambda x : pd.Series([2018,2019,2020]).isin(x['year']).all() & x['c'].diff().fillna(1).gt(0).all()).reindex(df.a).values